# Priority and timing between enchantments and instants

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have priority and cast an [Unholy Strength](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnholy%20Strength%5d) on a just summoned 2/3 creature, then, passing priority, my opponent casts a [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d) on that creature, does my creature survive? The first spell that resolves is obviously the bolt, that deals 3 point of damage to the creature; but immediately after, will the 
Unholy Strength resolve (giving +2/+1), allowing the creature to survive?

Comment: In other words, we have a stack with lightning bolt on top of it, and then an enchant creature (f.e. unholy strenght). What happens? Do the damage send the creature to the graveyard, or unholy strenght has the time to resolve and save the creature?

Comment: I really disagree with the sign - "this question already has an answer here" - because beginners may find the two interactions quite different.Here we have  a stack with lightning bolt (instant) on top of it, and then an unholy strenght (enchant creature); in the linked question there are two instants, instead.

Comment: Who knows how the stack really works?Beginners still don't know very well if a certain type of spell goes on the stack or not,and therefore they need to know if there are differences in interaction between enchantments/instants/abilities,with other instants.To show the validity of the question I may talk about the case of a creature unmorphing itself:in this case,since it is a special action, the unmorphing WILL NOT GO on the stack.Therefore, interaction with it would be different (since opponent cannnot respond to it).Only experienced players,like Ikegami&Murgatroid,know how the stack works.

Answer (score 10):

It's not "immediately after" at all. Between the bolt resolving and the strength resolving, the game goes through a whole bunch of steps that are usually glossed over in casual play.

1. State-based actions are checked and then performed. This includes, but is not limited to, destroying creatures with lethal damage dealt to them, and causing players with 0 or less life to lose.
2. Repeat 1 until nothing new happens.
3. Abilities that triggered during the resolution of the bolt (e.g. "Whenever this creature is dealt damage") and during steps 1 and 2 are put on the stack.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 until nothing new happens
5. Players gain priority and may play instants and spells with flash.
6. If no player played anything, *now* the Unholy Strength resolves, sees that it has no valid target, and is removed from the stack to your graveyard with no effect.

Comment: Point of order: #4 is actually first, and #3 repeats the SBA check as well.  704.3

Comment: In other words, SBAs go first, then those repeat until nothing happens, then triggered abilities go on the stack, then you go back to the beginning of this sequence if anything happened in any of those steps.

Comment: @JonTheMoon You're right. I'll fix.

Comment: It's still a little off. step 4 should effectively by "Repeat steps 1-3 until nothing new happens", and then you don't need steps 5-7.

Comment: @murgatroid99 You're right. I thought the game kept putting triggered abilities on the stack until no new ones triggered, but it seems like there is just one wave of putting triggered abilities on the stack before going back to SBA (besides, _are_ there any abilities that would trigger from putting triggered abilities on the stack?) That does simplify the list.

Comment: [This scryfall search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Awhenever+o%3A%22becomes+the+target%22+o%3Aability) lists several cards with abilities that trigger from targets being chosen, which can happen while putting triggered abilities on the stack.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Becoming targets. Yes, of course. I should've thought about that. I mentioned the Betrayers Glasskites in a comment here just the other day.

Comment: Ok, it is correct. With "immediately after" I mean only on the stack. But it is important to precise it properly, as Arthur does.