# MTG - Priority and timing between instants and instants -

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Well, [returning back to the creature 2/3 just summoned](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/49271/12315), what happens if I have priority and cast an instant that gives +1/+1 to that creature, and then, giving priority to the opponent, he/she casts [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d) in order to kill the creature counting on that it resolves before my instant (giving +1/+1 to the 2/3 creature)?

In other words, here's the order of the spells:

1. Summoning of a 2/3 creature
2. Priority is mine, and I cast an instant (giving +1/+1 to the 2/3 creature just summoned)
3. I give priority to my opponent, and he casts a lightning bolt with the 2/3 creature as a target.

What happens? Does the Lightning Bolt kill the creature, or not? The stack is now:

- Lightning Bolt on the top
- My +1/+1 instant on the bottom

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101237/discussion-on-question-by-massimiliano-mtg-priority-and-timing-between-enchant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will kill the creature. After the Lightning Bolt resolves, state based actions will be checked:

> 704.1. State-based actions are game actions that happen automatically whenever certain conditions (listed below) are met. State-based actions don’t use the stack.
>
> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 117, “Timing and Priority”), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event.

One of those checks will destroy the 2/3 creature:

> 704.5g If a creature has toughness greater than 0, and the total damage marked on it is greater than or equal to its toughness, that creature has been dealt lethal damage and is destroyed. Regeneration can replace this event.

This happens before the +1/+1 instant can come to the rescue.

Comment: Returning back about the timing between enchantments and instants, I have to tell you why I asked a so apparently simple question. My understanding about this kind of situations changed when I saw a just summoned Ajani Vengeant survive to a lightning bolt, cast in response of the first one. Isn't weird - I thought - that a planswalker ability (that is the same as a sorcery, isn't it?) resolves before an instant? Later, I understood that the planswalker survive because the added loyalty counter is considered as a payment(it is not an effect). Is it correct? i think it is, but it is weird too...

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and I agree it feels a little weird.

Comment: @Massimiliano It seems strange until you consider the abilities that take away counters, and the amount of counter shenanigans that can happen if the counter removal was an effect and not a cost. And then how convoluted the rules would be if adding counters and removing counters were different. Also, if it is Ajani you were really wondering about, then I really think that that's what you ought to have asked about.

Comment: First of all,let me thank you Arthur,'cause you have been so fast in resolving my first - and fake - simple question.Yes,it was Ajani that just let me wonder how weird this game is,sometimes.But I anyway proceed to question you,in order to read your comments&reactions about this...one step at a time.Don't you think that this game could bring people to bad discussions when resolving situations like the one concerning the first loyalty ability of Ajani?There could be discussions in EVERY MTG GAME  you play,since you couldn't know what happens in advance.Just answer to this, but tell the truth...

Comment: Most planeswalkers have some ability that increases their loyalty counters. The adding or removing of Loyalty counters is done as a cost, and costs cannot be responded to. It may seem a bit 'strange', having a 'cost' that is beneficial. However, it is completely unambiguous in the rules how this works. If your opponent's Ajani resolved, they now have priority. (The active player always has priority first when an effect resolves.) They can choose to use Ajani's +1. As a cost, Ajani gains a Loyalty counter. It puts the ability on the stack. You can now respond to this ability.

Comment: First of all, thank you Arthur once again. Anyway,my FIRST (not this one, but the linked one) question wasn't completely fake, and useless.Now,it is a fast-recovering rule,useful in resolving similar situation, for example when forgetting the rules, playing again after many years. Secondly, it shows the list of many actions performed automatically - I forgot some of them - especially SBA's. Third...well, I've got another question...why do you edit the answer? The first one you give shows a list of 9 sub-rules, while the definitive one shows only six.Answer when it is possible,if you want to.